# Passing arguments to actions in Redux

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am using the redux toolkit, (the new update of redux in case you're still using the deprecated older version) with React and I am using the `createAsyncThunk` method (or middleware if you prefer) to perform an API call to my backend API.

Here, I can do two things, either run the async call inside the component and check whether the API call succeeds or fails, and render something based on that, or I can perform the Async API call inside the action creator itself (inside the `createSlice` in case you're using the Redux toolkit).

Personally, I believe that the second approach is more abstract and cleaner for the components, but the main problem is that I *can't* handle the errors there. In other words, take this example, I wanted to `getAllPosts`, I can simply `dispatch` an action using `dispatch(getAllPosts())` within the component, and let the Async logic and error handling be inside the action creator `getAllPosts`. But in case of a failed Async call, I can't return an error to the component to render a red message saying "there was an error while fetching the posts".

I thought I could pass a callback function as an argument to the `getAllPosts` action creator, and make this callback function a callback that only runs in case of a *failure*. ex:

```
dispatch(getAllPosts(payloadObj, ()=> { /* do something here in case of an error* / } ))
```

The questions are:

- What do you think about my solution? Is it the best or is there a standardized way of doing this?
- How do I pass the callback function argument I described to the getAllPosts method? Can I simply add a second argument to the `getAllPosts` method? Or is that not possible in redux-toolkit? Do I have to pass my callback function as the first argument? But having it the first argument will make redux-toolkit wrap it inside a `payload` property because it's *assumed* that what I am passing is a new state.

Comment: You could update the store when an error occurs and render the message from your component

Comment: @AsafAviv, can you explain this point?

Comment: You can create a state of allPosts with loading/error/data properties and update it on start/success/failure of the request

Comment: @AsafAviv If you mean that I will store something like `showError: false` inside the store, then NO, I am not going to do that because this isn't how the fancy term **programming** was made for. Hm >:(

Comment: @AsafAviv, let's forget about the other suggestions, and let's just answer my second question, okay? 

Comment: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#fetching-data-with-createasyncthunk

Comment: @AsafAviv, thanks, now I'm convinced and I'm using that approach because of your answer, but still I think that they must add a possibility to pass other arguments to the action creators.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is to follow the pattern shown in [Redux Essentials Part 5: Async Logic - Checking Thunk Results in Components](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components).

If the thunk function returns a promise, that will be returned from `dispatch(thatAsyncThunk())`.

RTK's `createAsyncThunk` in particular will end up returning a promise with a special `.unwrap()` method that either returns the result if successful, or throws an error if it failed.

So, the right technique in a component is:

```js
const fetchPokemonByName = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetchPokemonByName',
  async (name) => {
    const res = await imaginaryPokemonApi.getByName(name);
    return res.data;
  }
)

// later, in a component
function SomeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const pokemon = await dispatch(fetchPokemonByName("pikachu")).unwrap();
      console.log("Entry: ", pokemon);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch pokemon: ", err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you actually don't have to create an asyncThunk, you can simply make the `handleClick` an async function, and perform the fetching inside this function, like doing `await axios.get('my/api/pokemons')`, then the result of that will be used inside `dispatch(addPokemons(apiRes))` all within the component's `handleClick` function

Comment: Also, this approach will have me to do `try{}` `catch(err){}` everytime I want to query the back end api in my code,

Comment: I'm rather lost at what your question is atm tbh :) Backing up: our _primary_ recommendation for data fetching with Redux is to use [RTK Query](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics), rather than writing thunks and reducers yourself. If you're not using RTKQ, then we _do_ still recommend using thunks rather than fetching manually in event handlers. `createAsyncThunk` does a lot of work for you there. Finally, you only need to do the `.unwrap()` thing _if_ you also want the component to do more error handling beyond the Redux part.

Comment: I'd specifically recommend watching my recent talk [The Evolution of Redux Async Logic](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/), which talks about the various approaches and what our recommendations are today.

Comment: ok wait.. I'll read the link of RTK Query this is new to me, maybe I'll find something there